# Excel VBA - Slow update of SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, sql-update

I am using this following VBA Code to export a range form my Excel worksheet to a SQL Server table ([original source here](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm))

```
Function ExportRangeToSQL(sourceRange As Range, conString As String, tableName As String) As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim con As Object
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.ConnectionString = conString
    con.Open

    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    ' Do work within Transaction:'
    Dim level As Long
    level = con.BeginTrans

    cmd.CommandType = 1             ' adCmdText'

    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rst

        ' Get Column Mapping Information from DB:'
        Set .ActiveConnection = con
        .Source = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & tableName
        .CursorLocation = 3         ' adUseClient'
        .LockType = 4               ' adLockBatchOptimistic'
        .CursorType = 0             ' adOpenForwardOnly'
        .Open

        ' Column mappings'
        Dim tableFields(100) As Integer
        Dim rangeFields(100) As Integer

        Dim exportFieldsCount As Integer
        exportFieldsCount = 0

        Dim col As Integer
        Dim index As Integer

        ' Map range Columns to DB Columns:'
        For col = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            index = Application.Match(.Fields(col).Name, sourceRange.Rows(1), 0)
            If index > 0 Then
                exportFieldsCount = exportFieldsCount + 1
                tableFields(exportFieldsCount) = col
                rangeFields(exportFieldsCount) = index
            End If
        Next

        If exportFieldsCount = 0 Then
            ExportRangeToSQL = 1
            GoTo ConnectionEnd
        End If


        ' Load the Range into the Recordset:'
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = sourceRange.Value

        Dim row As Long
        Dim rowCount As Long
        rowCount = UBound(arr, 1)

        Dim val As Variant

        For row = 2 To rowCount
            .AddNew
            For col = 1 To exportFieldsCount
                val = arr(row, rangeFields(col))
                If IsEmpty(val) Then
                Else
                    .Fields(tableFields(col)) = val
                End If
            Next
        Next


        ' Update the table using the same RecordSet:'
        .UpdateBatch
    End With

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

    ExportRangeToSQL = 0

ConnectionEnd:

    con.CommitTrans

    con.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

End Function
```

Basically, it:

1. Creates a recordset based upon the table we wish to update
2. Maps each column of your update range to a field in the recordset
3. Updates the recordset with the data to be uploaded
4. Uses `Recordset.UpdateBatch` to update the table all at once.

I'm finding, though, that this is INCREDIBLY slow (for 1000-2000 records) and writing separate insert statements to be substantially faster (albeit not as pretty).

Any thoughts on how to make this faster?

Comment: 1) how long does it take for 1000-2000 records?, 2) how many columns?, 3) Have you profiled/instrumented/stepped through it to see which statements/sections are taking most of the time?

Comment: It's not too long - About 90 seconds for 1400 rows with 12 columns. I haven't done any profiling, but I can tell you that separate insert statements takes under a second.

Comment: What explicitly does "*separate insert statements takes under a second*" mean?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I mean actually creating the `insert into MyTable values (...)` statements for 1400 sets of values.

Comment: What about executing them? 1 second or 90 seconds?

Comment: @JohnBustos: I think it might be worth trying a different cursorType - for `UpdateBatch` operations you need to use either a *Keyset* or *Static* cursor...

Comment: @RBarryYoung, that is including executing them.

Comment: @OurManInBananas, thanks for the suggestion, but, unfortunately, no gains in time whatsoever :/

Comment: Try changing the cursor type as others have suggested.  Other than that, it seems likely that this is either a configuration/options problem or some kind of network/buffering problem.

Comment: @JohnBustos: So how long does it take to get to this line of code: `.UpdateBatch` ? And how long does that one line of code take?

Comment: @OurManInBananas, to get to the `UpdateBatch` takes milliseconds, then *at least* 30-60 seconds for that single line of code.

Comment: @JohnBustos: I think this is worth trying from another machine- if it's the same, then you'll need  to nail down where the communication bottleneck is as suggested by [RBarryYoung](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109122/rbarryyoung)..

Answer (score 3):

Please change this line of code:

```
.CursorType = 0             ' adOpenForwardOnly'
```

to

```
.CursorType = 4             ' adOpenStatic - could also use adOpenKeyset
```

as your cursor type is not optimised for update operations.

See the [MSDN Reference on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! - I tried it, but, unfortunately, no performance / speed gains....